# Recent versions of books such as Critique of Pure Reason

Tags: reference-request, rationality, reason

I am looking for books which have a critical view on reason and rationality especially in the light of all the new things we currently know in 21st century. In a sense maybe new versions or iterations of book such as Critique of Pure Reason by Immanuel Kant.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: Brandom's Making it Explicit was semi-jokingly compared to Critique of Pure Reason, you should probably start with his own self-introduction to it [Articulating Reasons](https://books.google.com/books/about/Articulating_Reasons.html?id=T1C2g9ZJJ3gC). But for a more substantive answer you'll have to be more specific than "critical view on reason and rationality especially in the light of all the new things" and "such as Critique of Pure Reason". There were lots of "new things" that reason and rationality have been criticized, or even denounced, for in varying degrees of severity.

Comment: Meillassoux' *After Finitude* is considered by some to be one of the more profound critical books on reason and rationality of recent years (read: after 2000). But I think the premise that we should reconsider anything because of "all the new things we currently know in the 21st century" is pretty much flawed. The human condition with regards to rationality and the insights into its limits did not change.

Answer (score 0):

I can't cite anything in particular off the top of my head, but I would look into intersections of philosophy and cognitive science (the latter of which started from a Kantian springboard AFAIK).